# JPopupMenu with focusable components causes flashing window frame

Tags: java, swing, jpopupmenu, focusable

I have a JPopupMenu that has a JTextField inside. If part of the menu is painted outside the main window, the window frame flashes. If all of the menu is painted within the window, there is no flashing. After some sleuthing, I found that if the JTextField is set to not be focusable, then the flashing stops. This isn't a viable solution as you can't click and type in the text field if it is not focusable.

In the example below, if you left click in the window, the popup will have a non focusable textfield and displays as expected. If you right click, the popup will have a focusable text field and the application frame will flash before the popup is displayed.

If you increase the size of the window to be larger than the popup, there will be no flashing in either case.

How can I get the menu to display without the application frame flashing when part of it displays outside the window?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class PopupTesting
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( () ->
        {
            JPopupMenu popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();

            for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
            {
                popupMenu.add( new JCheckBoxMenuItem( "A Menu " + i ) );
            }

            JTextField textField = new JTextField( "" );
            popupMenu.add( textField );

            JFrame frame = new JFrame( "Popup Testing" );
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
            JLabel header = new JLabel( "Header" );
            header.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 200, 100 ) );
            header.addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter()
            {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked( MouseEvent e )
                {
                    if( SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton( e ) )
                    {
                        textField.setFocusable( false );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        textField.setFocusable( true );
                    }
                    popupMenu.show( header, e.getX(), e.getY() );
                }
            } );


            frame.add( header );

            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible( true );
        } );
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding your content to an intermediate component (like `JPanel`) instead of adding it directly to the frame.  I'd also take a close look at [Bringing Up a Popup Menu](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2Ftutorial%2Fuiswing%2F%2F/components/menu.html#popup) - compare it's handling of the mouse events to yours.  In my testing, I was unable to replicate the issue

Comment: Does adding `popupMenu.setLightWeightPopupEnabled(false);` make a difference?

Comment: @MadProgrammer are you saying the above snippet doesn't produce a flashing window frame? I've only tested on Windows 10. I get the flashing with Java 11 and 21 on several workstations.

Comment: @VGR setting that boolean has no effect

Comment: @colomb I was testing it on MacOS, I made use of a `JPanel` as my primary container instead of `JFrame`

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yeah, this appears to be OS dependent. I tested under macOS and the above code works fine. Arch Linux / KDE has a different issue: when showing the popup with focusable items, the popup displays only for a split second, then disappears. I don't quite understand what you mean about the use of a JPanel vs a JFrame though. You need a JFrame to display a window.

Comment: @colomb Yes, but instead of placing your content directly on the `JFrame` as you have create a `JPanel` and use it as instead and then place the `JPanel` on the frame

Comment: @MadProgrammer Understood. Setting the JFrame's content pane to a JPanel makes this even stranger. Some clicks make the frame flash, while others do not. A click in the same place will sometimes flash the frame and sometimes not. Can't seem to figure out a pattern. Maybe its time to file a bug.